# How do i implement an asdf extension when using either numpy polynomial or astropy polynomial?

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

I want to store some Data in ASDF-files and want to use non implemented extensions. I want to extend other extensions, so i tried starting with the [Astropy](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/tree/master/astropy/io/misc/asdf) extensions.

I know how to write a working Extension for ASDF. But, The key issue is that the ASDF-file should always look like an ASDF-file created by an astropy polynomial. Creating a new extension where numpy polynomials are stored is not my purpose.
On the other side, the asdf file should always output an numpy polynomial.

This is what i started working on:

```py
import asdf
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P

# these 2 polynomials are equal
poly_np = P([0,0,0])
poly_astropy = models.Polynomial1D(degree=2)

# this is the usual way how to save an astropy polynomial
target = asdf.AsdfFile({'astropy_poly':poly_astropy})
# inline is just for readability...
target.write_to('poly_astropy.yaml',all_array_storage='inline')

# does not work since numpy polynomials are not 'known' by asdf
target = asdf.AsdfFile({'numpy_poly':poly_np})
target.write_to('poly_np.yaml',all_array_storage='inline')
```

I tried to change the class PolynomialType in [polynomial.py](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/tree/master/astropy/io/misc/asdf/tags/transform) from astropy so that it will accept the type 'numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial'. But the issue was still that the object could not be represented. So where do i need to do a change to get my polynomial.py working? Or maybe my way of overwriting the astropy class was wrong?

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P
from numpy.testing import assert_array_equal

from asdf import yamlutil

from astropy import modeling
from astropy.io.misc.asdf.tags.transform.basic import TransformType

class PolynomialType_np(TransformType):
    name = "transform/polynomial"
    types = ['astropy.modeling.models.Polynomial1D',
             'astropy.modeling.models.Polynomial2D',
             'numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial']

    # from asdf file to np polynomial
    @classmethod
    def from_tree_transform(cls, node, ctx):
        coefficients = np.asarray(node['coefficients'])
        return P(coefficients)


    # from any polynomial to asdf
    @classmethod
    def to_tree_transform(cls, model, ctx):
        # np.polynomial added
        if isinstance(model, np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial):
            coefficients = p.coef
        elif isinstance(model, modeling.models.Polynomial1D):
            coefficients = np.array(model.parameters)
        elif isinstance(model, modeling.models.Polynomial2D):
            degree = model.degree
            coefficients = np.zeros((degree + 1, degree + 1))
            for i in range(degree + 1):
                for j in range(degree + 1):
                    if i + j < degree + 1:
                        name = 'c' + str(i) + '_' + str(j)
                        coefficients[i, j] = getattr(model, name).value
        node = {'coefficients': coefficients}
        return yamlutil.custom_tree_to_tagged_tree(node, ctx)

    # astropy classmethod updated with np.arrays
    @classmethod
    def assert_equal(cls, a, b):
        # TODO: If models become comparable themselves, remove this.
        TransformType.assert_equal(a, b)
        assert (isinstance(a, (modeling.models.Polynomial1D, modeling.models.Polynomial2D, np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial)) and
                isinstance(b, (modeling.models.Polynomial1D, modeling.models.Polynomial2D, np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial)))
        if (isinstance(a, (modeling.models.Polynomial1D, modeling.models.Polynomial2D)) and 
            isinstance(b, (modeling.models.Polynomial1D, modeling.models.Polynomial2D))):
            assert_array_equal(a.parameters, b.parameters)
        elif (isinstance(a, (modeling.models.Polynomial1D, modeling.models.Polynomial2D)) and
              isinstance(b, np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial)):
            assert_array_equal(a.parameters, b.coeff)
        elif (isinstance(b, (modeling.models.Polynomial1D, modeling.models.Polynomial2D)) and
              isinstance(a, np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial)):
            assert_array_equal(a.coeff, b.parameters)
        elif (isinstance(a, np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial) and
              isinstance(b, np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial)):
            assert_array_equal(a.coeff, b.coeff)
```

Comment: Given that you want to extend the existing `PolynomialType` class to support Numpy polynomials (a feature that might also be worth submitting upstream as a patch), it might make sense for you to instead make your new type a *subclass* of `PolynomialType`.  This way, with some care, you can add more functionality without having to re-implement as much duplicate functionality.

Comment: Then you might have to do some hacking around to actually remove the existing `PolynomialType` from the [type registry](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/fc01449bf26e027e3467c6f228fd43bbc665b9f8/astropy/io/misc/asdf/types.py#L14).  It would be nice if there were an explicit way to override an existing type in the registry, but at the moment there is not.  So you might have to do something hacky like `_astropy_asdf_types.remove(PolynomialType)`.  It should be okay since you're still representing the polynomial the same way in ASDF.

Comment: Thanks for your tipps, they helped me resolving my problem. 
If someone whishes to see my results feel free to comment - i might invest some time posting a response.

Comment: Yeah, I'm glad you were able to get it working.  I had been meaning to see if I could do it myself, and post my solution as an answer if I got it working. But I haven't had a chance yet.  You should certainly, if you can, post an answer to your own question with the solution you came up with.  If you do (and comment here to remind me) I'll gladly review your solution as well and see if I can make any other suggestions.

Comment: I answered my question with your suggested solutions. ;-) Feel free to make other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two solutions @Iguananaut suggested:

### Solution 1

This is the solution where you override the `PolynomialType` registry by force.

```py
# the code from above and then the following
from astropy.io.misc.asdf.extension import AstropyAsdfExtension
from astropy.io.misc.asdf.types import _astropy_asdf_types

_astropy_asdf_types.remove(
    astropy.io.misc.asdf.tags.transform.polynomial.PolynomialType)

#this will work now
target = asdf.AsdfFile({'numpy_poly':poly_np},extensions=AstropyAsdfExtension())
target.write_to('poly_np.yaml',all_array_storage='inline')
```

### Solution 2

This is the solution where you create a subclass of `PolynomialType` where you add the functionality of adding numpy polynomials. Since its not really necessary to read them as numpy polynomials, they are read as astropy polynomials.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P
from numpy.testing import assert_array_equal

import asdf
from asdf import yamlutil

from astropy import modeling
from astropy.io.misc.asdf.tags.transform.polynomial import PolynomialType

from astropy.io.misc.asdf.extension import AstropyAsdfExtension

class PolynomialTypeNumpy(PolynomialType):
    @classmethod
    def to_tree(cls, model, ctx):
        coefficients = model.coef
        node = {'coefficients': coefficients}
        return yamlutil.custom_tree_to_tagged_tree(node, ctx)

    # could/should add assert_equal from above


# And then this works.
target = asdf.AsdfFile({'numpy_poly':P([0,0,0])},
    extensions=AstropyAsdfExtension())
target.write_to('poly_np.yaml',all_array_storage='inline')
```